# MySql : fill a column thanks to a IF condition ? (see example inside ;) )

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement, select, conditional-statements

I have a database table that looks like this:

| Name | Town | Type | Brand | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | London | Big | Sony | 1020 |
| Carlos | Rio | Big | Nokia | 050 |
| Francois | Paris | Little | Sony | 250 |

I need to get:

| Name | Town | Big_Sony | Big_Nokia | Little_Sony | Little_Nokia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | London | 1020 |  |  |  |
| Carlos | Rio |  | 050 |  |  |
| Francois | Paris |  |  | 250 |  |

Is there any possibility, with IF condition, to fill the right column?

I don't really know if I'd be possible to do it...

Thanks you for your precious help :-)

edit : I tried the Forpas suggestion, but I just add

| Name | Town | Type | Brand | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Roberto | Roma | Little | Sony | 100 |

but I have not more result :( see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=41281e45a3c8c5eb84f99405aa867216)

Comment: You missed a comma in the INSERT statement before the row of 'Roberto'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name, Town,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Big' AND Brand = 'Sony' THEN Ref END) Big_Sony,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Big' AND Brand = 'Nokia' THEN Ref END) Big_Nokia,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Little' AND Brand = 'Sony' THEN Ref END) Little_Sony,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Little' AND Brand = 'Nokia' THEN Ref END) Little_Nokia
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Name, Town
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c8b12b698edb985a74c02b84800769d4).
Results:

| Name | Town | Big_Sony | Big_Nokia | Little_Sony | Little_Nokia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carlos | Rio | null | 50 | null | null |
| Francois | Paris | null | null | 250 | null |
| Smith | London | 1020 | null | null | null |

Comment: Hello Forpas, thanks you for you very quick aswser :) But I try to add a record and I don't have any result : see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=41281e45a3c8c5eb84f99405aa867216

Comment: @AbouIlyès You missed a comma in the INSERT statement:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=945751b02fab4498835a69e4ab58b84e